# двумерный массив в рекурсивном классе java

Tags: java, массивы, рекурсия

есть заполненный числовой двумерный массив А[N][W] (по условию верхняя строка нули, а справа внизу максимум) и вектор w[N], и требуется следуя из крайней правой нижней точки переместиться к следующему значению по правилам:

1. если A[k][s] == 0 то завершить выполнение класса;
2. если A[k][s] == A[k-1][s] то выполнить заново для k-1;
3. в ином случае записать номер строки в вывод и выполнить заново для k-1 и s-w[k].

пытался сделать так, но выдает ошибки при обращении к классу:

```
String res = new String();
res = null;
int k = N;
int s = W;
res = Num(A[N][W],k,s,w[N-1],res);

 private static String Num(int A[][], int k, int s, int w[], String res)                  {
        if (A[k][s] == 0) {
        }

        if (A[k][s] == A[k-1][s]) {
            Num(A[k-1][s],k-1,s,w[k-1],res);
        }
        else {
            int d = w[k];
            Num(A[k-1][s],k-1,s-d,w[k-1],res);
            res = res + k;
        }
        return res;
  }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, добавляйте всегда ошибку в вопрос

Comment: до этого есть сформированные таблица для массива чисел А и числовой вектор w

Comment: @Дмитрий какую ошибку и на какой строке? Что эта строка делает и что в неё передается? Вы это все знаете, а нам предлагаете гадать... С учетом того, что все ваши переменные однобуквенные, непомешали бы ещё и комментарии к ним.

Comment: @Дмитрий "если A[k][s] == 0 то завершить выполнение класса;" не класса, а метода и с каким результатом?

Comment: ошибка следующая:   java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[][]   для строк с рекурсией

Comment: Виктор, да, извиняюсь, конечно метода, с результатом res, каким бы он ни был(так он всегда будет и с первого шага метод никак не начнется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала первая ошибка:

> если A[k][s] == 0 то завершить выполнение класса;

не класса, а метода (это к терминологии).

```
if (A[k][s] == 0) {
}
```

тут вы не завершаете метод, а просто ничего не делаете. Тут 2 варианта как при этом условии выйти:

```
if (A[k][s] == 0) {
     return res;
}
```

---

```
Num(A[k-1][s],k-1,s-d,w[k-1],res);
```

Таким вызовом метода вы передаете не массивы, а элементы массива. В первом и предпоследнем аргументе.

Как поправить - передавать массив а не элемент:

```
private static String Num(int A[][], int k, int s, int w[], String res){
    if (A[k][s] == 0) {
    }

    if (A[k][s] == A[k-1][s]) {
        Num(A,k-1,s,w,res);
    }
    else {
        int d = w[k];
        Num(A,k-1,s-d,w,res);
        res = res + k;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!